# How to programmatically authenticate to Azure Kubernetes (AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory

I'm having an AKS cluster setup and recently enabled the Azure Active Directory integration. I'm having a C# application that is running outside of the Kubernetes cluster that is creating Kubernetes Jobs. Therefore, I'm using the C# `KubernetesClient` package which has been working fine before (and still is). However, it is using a so called "local account" (so the local admin user) which is not integrated with the Active Directory. My goal is to completely deactivate the local accounts in the long run, meaning I need a different way of authenticating. As the Kubernetes Cluster is now fully integrated with the AAD, I preferrably want to use a service principal for authentication.

Microsoft is not providing any documentation on how to achieve this and the support hasn't been particular helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually get an Access Token for the Kubernetes environment. This can be done with the following code:

```cs
var credFactory = new AzureCredentialsFactory();
var credentials = credFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
    "CLIENT_ID",
    "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "TENANT_ID",
    AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud
);

var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithSubscription("SUBSCRIPTION_ID");

var kubeConfigBytes = azure.KubernetesClusters.GetUserKubeConfigContents(
    "K8S_RESOURCE_GROUP",
    "K8S_CLUSTER_NAME"
);


var kubeConfigRaw = KubernetesClientConfiguration.LoadKubeConfig(new MemoryStream(kubeConfigBytes));
var authProvider  = kubeConfigRaw.Users.Single().UserCredentials.AuthProvider;
if (!authProvider.Name.Equals("azure", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    throw new Exception("Invalid k8s auth provider!");

// Token Helper is a small helper utility that I use instead of MSAL
// This method is doing a POST call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
var token = TokenHelper.GetTokenByClientCredentials(
    "CLIENT_ID",
    "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "TENANT_ID",
    "6dae42f8-4368-4678-94ff-3960e28e3630/.default" // This scope is always the same. It's the "Azure Kubernetes Service AAD Server" app from Microsoft. (az ad sp show --id 6dae42f8-4368-4678-94ff-3960e28e3630)
).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

authProvider.Config["access-token"] = token.AccessToken;
authProvider.Config["expires-on"]   = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(token.ExpiresIn).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();

var kubeConfig    = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigObject(kubeConfigRaw);
var kubernetes = new Kubernetes(kubeConfig);
```

Please keep in mind that the token expires every hour, so you need to creat a new `Kubernetes` instance regularly. Also note that this only takes care of the **Authentication**, not **Authorization**. Meaning, you will be able to login, but your service principal might not be allowed to read/edit any kubernetes resources. For that to work you need to assign a `Role` or `CluterRole` to your service principal as described [HERE](https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin#service-principal-login-flow-non-interactive).

Comment: Where is TokenHelper?

Comment: also, it seems the "authProvider" is not used later?